# Controlling parindent in enumerate inside customized list environment

Tags: spacing, environments, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to control the indentation of paragraphs in an enumerated list that is inside a customized list environment. I find that changing \parindent in the inner list has no effect.

Here's an example that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\exlabelwidth}
\settowidth{\exlabelwidth}{\small 99.99}
\newlength{\exlabelsep}
\setlength{\exlabelsep}{0.5em}
\newlength{\exsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\exsymbolwidth}{\small\ensuremath{*}}

\newcounter{exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{exercise}}   
\newcommand{\exitem}{}
\newenvironment{exercises}%
  {\begin{list}{\exitem}{%
    \usecounter{exercise}%  
    \small%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\exlabelwidth}%
    \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%  
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\exlabelwidth}% 
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{\exsymbolwidth}%     
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{\exlabelsep}%   
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%      
    }%
  }%
  {\end{list}%
}  
\newcommand{\ex}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\exitem}{%
    \makebox[\exsymbolwidth][r]{#1}\hspace{\exlabelsep}%
    \makebox[\exlabelwidth][r]{\bfseries\theexercise}}\item%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercises}
  \ex
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
  \ex 
    \lipsum[3]
    \begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent]
      \item 
        \lipsum[1]
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{exercises}
\end{document}
```

The environment is based on advice I received on tex.stackexchange. I tried to make the code shorter, but I get errors. What I would like to be able to do is to have the second paragraph in the enumerate environment indented. Right now, it starts flush left regardless of whether I use the enumitem package and set parsep to zero or not.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Use `listparindent=15pt` explicitly (which is the default `\parindent` outside the `enumerate` environment) rather than setting it to `\parindent`. Does that help?

Comment: Setting \setlength{\listparindent}{15pt} in \newenvironment{exercises} has no effect.

Comment: Frank has provided the location where you need to supply `listparindent=15pt`; not in `exercises`, but as the option to `enumerate`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that on one hand you use the `enumitem` package but then you also define your own lists via the `list` environment of LaTeX. The `enumitem` package doesn't know about your new list and gets confused.

Basically what happens is that the following code in `\enit@preset` makes the wrong choice:

```
   \ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne
     \enit@outerparindent\parindent
   \else
     \parindent\enit@outerparindent
   \fi
```

The idea of this code is to save the outer `\parindent` value in `\enit@outerparindent` when we enter the first level of lists and if we enter a nested list reuse the saved value instead. Now unfortunately your new list doesn't know about this so nothing gets saved. But if the  `enumerate` is entered it is in fact already on level 2 and therefore `\parindent` gets the current value of `\enit@outerparindent` which is, of course, still zero.

So either you simply give `listparindent` and explicit value when you call enumarate, e.g.

```
\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt,listparindent=15pt]
```

or, if you like this properly fixed you could set `\enit@outerparindent` in your definition of `exercises` if it exists (i.e., if `enumitem` was loaded), e.g.,

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{exercises}%
  {\begin{list}{\exitem}{%
    \@ifundefined{enit@outerparindent}{}%  if this command exists set it, otherwise do nothing
        {\ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne
            \enit@outerparindent\parindent
         \else
            \parindent\enit@outerparindent
        \fi
       }%
    \usecounter{exercise}%  
    \small%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\exlabelwidth}%
    \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%  
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\exlabelwidth}% 
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{\exsymbolwidth}%     
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{\exlabelsep}%   
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0.0cm}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%      
    }%
  }%
  {\end{list}}
\makeatother
```

Because of the `@` signs you need `\makeatletter ...\makeatother`.

Comment: @JavierBezos perhaps enumitem should patch the list environment to properly set this for manually constructed lists.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: I find that the fix proposed by Frank only works if I set \enit@outerparindent *and* keep \begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt,listparindent=15pt]. But his reply suggests that either I do this *or* I set \enit@outerparindent. Did I misunderstand his reply?

Comment: it shoud be enough to do one or the other (and it works here just changing your exercise env as indicated).

Comment: I find I have to do both (i.e., add your code segment and add [parsep=0pt,listparindent=15pt]) otherwise nothing changes. [I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012). The log file shows also that I'm using  enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2.]

Comment: @user1362373 send me your example directly at frank.mittelbach at latex-project.org